# How to replicate/simulate experiments done on dsp kit 6713 without using hardware?

Tags: c, embedded, signal-processing, dsp, ti-ccstudio

Although i posted this question on DSP SE yesterday but still couldn't find any helpful reply there so i am reposting my question here

Due to covid, our university is now offering online classes to under grad students, even labs are conducted online.

But we are bit confused regarding evaluation? We make videos of demonstration of dsp kit 6713 and upload them to web and share their link with students.

But question is how we can evaluate / assess learning of students especially their ability of C programming to program DSP kit and especially in starting labs experiments for example switching on/off Led using dip switches available on dsp kit 6713.

It isn't practical to deliver each student a dsp kit at home, please recommend other solutions!

Comment: again, you state you need to stick to the department-given syllabus, but what is the point of teaching students to blink an LED with an expensive DSP kit, which relies on an especially anachronistic and hard-to-program piece of software environment? That's not what these DSPs are used of (so,teaching that has little benefit, you can teach them to blink an LED with a 5€ microcontroller board),and it doesn't teach about what you need to know to effectively make use of these heavily signal-processing optimized chips. Find flexibility in your syllabus to either teach DSPs or LED blinking sensibly!

Comment: That is a **very** old board -- roughly 20 years, given that it came out in the era of Windows 98 and Windows 2000. If it's available at all, the markup is exorbitant! You need to face the fact that it's time to revamp your course materials for something more modern.

Comment: Granted that you can do limited amounts of DSP on something like the TI MSP, why not port the coursework to a bulk buy of $5 or $10 MSP430 Launchpads or other very low cost platform?  These have LEDs, buttons, an ADC/DAC channel or two, and you can program in C ... or even Ada.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to write and debug your C code on a PC and then compile it and test it on your embedded target once ready.

I've been successfully using Microsoft Visual Studio since 1998 for this kind of activities.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio from Monday to Thursday and then test the code on my targets on Friday.

Microsoft Visual Studio Community edition is free for open source projects, students, teachers and makers.

---

You don't need at all to emulate DSP's hardware registers on your PC.

Let's imagine for example that some input data enters the DSP from a hardware interface that the PC doesn't have.

In this case, just input the data in a C source file like:

```
int input_data[8] = {12,654,-89,23432,-5453,7565,51099,-1};
```

If, for example, input data come from a DSP hardware interface and are random integer numbers, you may use srand() and rand() C functions.

---

If you need to turn on a led on your DSP board just use the printf() function:

```
void led__turn_on (void)
{    
    printf("Led on\n");
}

void led__turn_off (void)
{    
    printf("Led off\n");
}
```

---

You may also take a step forward to hardware emulation:

Implement those functions for your DSP using the very same name:

```
 void led__turn_on (void)
 {    
    P1 |= 0x01; 
 }

 void led__turn_ff (void)
 {    
     P1 &= ~0x01;
 }
```

Configure your DSP toolchain compliler to compile these functions.

---

Testing C algorithms on a PC platform first is an industry common practice standard.

Comment: Yep, pretty much what I told OP over at DSP.SE: Teach your students to write signal processing code on a PC; no need nor benefit throwing them into a slightly obscure DSP-core specific IDE and hardware platform just to allow them to blink an LED or observe DIP switches, both things nobody would do in real life with a DSP chip like that, but with a 1€ microcontroller.

Comment: Please explain your last code fragement. Specially what is meant by "P1"in your last code fragement?Is it referring to port1 or input1 or something else?and also please explain the the two logical comparison operations involving "P1".Thanks

Comment: P1 is the name of the hardware register of PORT 1. It's a pretty standard name across many embedded platforms. In some DSPs or microcontrollers P1 is called PA. The 2 logical operations write 1 and then 0 in bit b0 of PORT 1 which is an input/output port.